# Angular, changing views without destroying original view

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am using ui.router state provider to swap views.
I want to be able to leave the original view in the exact state that it was in before it switches to the next view, because most likely users will toggle back and forth between views frequently.
According to the docs (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), the views get destroyed upon switching states.
Is there a way to override the default behavior and 'cache' that view somehow.
I don't even care if I just have to 'hide' the original view, and keep it in the dom.
I  guess I'm just looking for best practice on ho to accomplish this.

Thanks and bunch!
A rough example of my code below:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: '/view1',
            views: {
                'View1': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
                    controller: 'Ctr1'
                }
            },
            data: {
                tab: 'tabname'
            }
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('view2', {
            url: '/view2',
            views: {
                'View2': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/view2.html',
                    controller: 'Ctr2'
                }
            },
            data: {
                tab: 'tabname'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this.

However, you could maintain the state of your controller in a service/factory, and reload the controller state when you navigate back to the same view.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like in your case you want to swap views once an action is taken (possibly button click and etc.)? Maybe you could leverage a model that you would use to $compile your views once and every time the swap happens. I had somewhat similar scenario I had to deal with and was able to do this: [Angularjs how to toggle/replace/revert dom element in a row on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651372/angularjs-how-to-toggle-replace-revert-dom-element-in-a-row-on-button-click)

Hope this helps.